# Delete periods at end of line in Google Docs RegEx

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm having trouble using regular expressions in Google Docs to delete periods at the end of every line.

I tried importing the text into Microsoft Word but I don't know how to make the macro. All I have is this code:

```
Sub doRegexFindReplace()
Dim objRegex As RegExp
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim fnd As Match
Dim strSample As String

    strSample = "First product code is fox 12, second one is fox 22, and third product is fox 45."
    
    Set objRegex = New RegExp
    
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "(fox) (\d+)"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        strSample = .Replace(strSample, "$1$2")
    End With
    
    Debug.Print strSample
End Sub
```

It might be too complex to figure out. That's ok if it is.

Comment: Is this for MSWord/VBA? Or for google docs as your title implies? Google Docs does not support VBA, so you cannot use this code.

Comment: If you're using Google Docs, why did you tag it MS-Word and VBA? They're totally different things, and VBA does not work in Google Docs.

Comment: In Basic `YourFile = "Text." & VBCRLF & "Text2." & VBCRLF` and 
`MsgBox Replace(YourFile, "." & VBCRLF, VBCRLF)`. There is no need for RegEx.

Comment: Just thought I could transpile the VB to Google Apps Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The regex for a trailing period would be `\.$` Now I don’t know if that will work in Google Docs. The `\` is the escaping character, which you need because in the RegEx world `.` is a reserved keyword. The `$` means end of line.

Comment: It doesn't work in Google Docs. I'm trying Word now.